# Can I have ubuntu forget about unmet dependency errors?

Tags: 13.04, dependencies

I was trying to install adobe reader and it didn't finish installing. Then I decided that I dont need adobe reader and how do I have ubuntu think everything is fine and there are no unmet dependencies or have ubuntu get those dependencies? I need to resolve this error because my system is running out of memory because of apps and I cant install or uninstall packages. I have tried `sudo apt-get install -f` and I get this:

```
[sudo] password for harley: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  acroread-bin
Suggested packages:
  libldap2 libgnome-speech7
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acroread-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 213 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 60.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 142 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring/partner acroread-bin i386 9.5.5-1raring1 [60.1 MB]
Fetched 60.1 MB in 35s (1,676 kB/s)                 
(Reading database ... 158479 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking acroread-bin (from .../acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/plugins', which is also in package adobe-flashplugin 11.2.202.297-0raring1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
         dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
harley@Harley-PC:~$
```

I tried `sudo apt-get remove acroread-bin` and I get this

```
[sudo] password for harley: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'acroread-bin' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
acroread : Depends: acroread-bin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried all of the soloutions from How do I resolve unmet dependencies? that I could (all of the ones that use terminal only)

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get remove acroread-bin` and let us know if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you solved the problem, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is essentially no way to make Ubuntu *ignore* all unmet dependency errors. And if you did achieve that, then you would create a system in an inconsistent state where different parts couldn't work together as designed. Which would be bad.

But if you decide to back out of installing something, that you *can* do. Most of the time, you can successfully uninstall a stuck "half-installed" package. For some packages, this should be avoided (or simulated first with `apt-get -s` to make sure removing them won't remove lots of other needed packages). But for something like Adobe Reader, it should be safe to go ahead and attempt uninstallation, [like roadmr suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333438/can-i-have-ubuntu-forget-about-unmet-dependency-errors#comment424571_333438):

```
sudo apt-get remove acroread-bin
```

This will most likely also uninstall other Adobe Reader related packages (any that depend on `acroread-bin`). But you want that, because those packages cannot run without it.

If you get errors removing `acroread-bin`, of course please let us know.

Alternatively (whether or not there are errors removing it), you might just want to try some of the solutions to [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Presumably with `sudo apt-get remove acroread acroread-bin`