# ubuntu resolve unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, deja-dup

I have tried to upgrade from ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04, it stopped upgrading and offered a partial upgrade which I didn't do. Right now I'm having an issue with `deja-dup-monitor` which is consuming about 7GB of ram. I'm trying to uninstall it. But whenever I install or uninstall using `apt-get` it shows a message saying `packages have unmet dependencies`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2) but 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
 cups-core-drivers : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2) but 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
 cups-daemon : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2) but 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
 dmsetup : Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.90) but 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libcupsmime1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2) but 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 208-8ubuntu8.2)
 lvm2 : Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.90) but 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 is to be installed
        Depends: dmeventd (> 2:1.02.90) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `dpkg --configure -a` ,it failed with lot of errors.
`apt-get -f install` also failed with errors.

When i run `apt-get -f install` i get the following errors.

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-53.2ubuntu12) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K02delllctservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'mongod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: warning: script 'delllctservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'delllctservicecontent' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service tlp and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service delllctservice if started
insserv: There is a loop at service tlp if started
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service hdapsd at depth 1
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service tlp and delllctservicecontent if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service delllctservicecontent at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service tlp at depth 1
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping delllctservicecontent depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: warning: script 'K02delllctservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'mongod' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mongod'
insserv: warning: script 'delllctservice' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'delllctservicecontent' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service tlp and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service delllctservice if started
insserv: There is a loop at service tlp if started
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service hdapsd at depth 1
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service tlp and delllctservicecontent if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service delllctservicecontent at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service tlp at depth 1
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting delllctservice depends on tlp and therefore on 
insserv: Stopping delllctservicecontent depends on tlp and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of util-linux:
 util-linux depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
 util-linux
```

EDIT : This is the output of `apt-cache policy cups libcups2 cups-core-drivers libcups2 cups-daemon dmsetup libdevmapper1.02.1 libcupsmime1 libpam-systemd systemd lvm2 libdevmapper1.02.1 dmeventd`

```
cups:
  Installed: 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcups2:
  Installed: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
cups-core-drivers:
  Installed: 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcups2:
  Installed: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
cups-daemon:
  Installed: 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
dmsetup:
  Installed: 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libdevmapper1.02.1:
  Installed: 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcupsmime1:
  Installed: 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2
  Candidate: 2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2
  Version table:
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.7.5-3ubuntu3.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libpam-systemd:
  Installed: 208-8ubuntu8.2
  Candidate: 219-7ubuntu6
  Version table:
     219-7ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
     219-7ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 208-8ubuntu8.2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
systemd:
  Installed: 219-7ubuntu6
  Candidate: 219-7ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 219-7ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     219-7ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
lvm2:
  Installed: 2.02.111-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.02.111-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.02.111-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libdevmapper1.02.1:
  Installed: 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
dmeventd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2:1.02.90-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy cups libcups2 cups-core-drivers libcups2 cups-daemon dmsetup libdevmapper1.02.1 libcupsmime1 libpam-systemd systemd lvm2 libdevmapper1.02.1 dmeventd`

Comment: I have edited the question and added the output as you have asked.

Comment: Some steps four you: `sudo apt-get install apt-file; sudo apt-file update` after that give me the output of `sudo apt-file search --regex K02delllctservice$`

Comment: I cant install any packages, whenever i try to install i tells me `The following packages have unmet dependencies`, so i cannot install the package `apt-file`

Answer (score 5):

This is very old, but I had a similar problem upgrading to 16.04, so I figured I'd post my solution here in case anyone else suffers from this.

The problem is that the `delllctservice` and `delllctservicecontent` scripts are missing LSB headers, which tell the system in what order to start them. Somehow during the upgrade this messes up the boot order, which breaks the insserv dependency calculation.

In order to fix this, temporarily move the `delllctservice` and `delllctservicecontent` scripts out of `/etc/init.d/`:

```
mkdir ~/dell-init.d-backup
sudo mv /etc/init.d/delllctservice* ~/dell-init.d-backup/
```

Then try to fix your packages again:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

You might need to do `sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends` instead depending on how bad things are.

After that, moving the scripts back to `/etc/init.d/` caused me no further problems.

I reported this to Dell here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1605952

Comment: Good thing I had the foresight to budget the entire Saturday for my distro upgrade.

Comment: For me a  `sudo dpkg --configure -a` happened to be enough, although it got stuck on several paclages (which I had to interrupt with ctrl-C) and maybe 50 of them had not been configured at the end. It was enough to login and get X up though.

Answer (score 3):

We have talked a lot in chat and much tried. Ultimately, I advise you to reinstall your system.

---

*What we have tried*

First step is, remove (temporary) `mongodb-server` via the command below, and yes, dear reader, wee need `--force-all`

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all mongodb-server
```

Second step, remove the outdated DELL packages

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all dell-e-star dell-eula dell-my-linux dell-recovery  dell-recovery-bootloader
```

Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` via

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and remove the `universe` entries to prevent the reinstall of `dell-recovery  dell-recovery-bootloader` for the next steps

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And as you wrote in the chat, you have `tlp` installed, therefore

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all tlp tlp-rdw kittyhawk-meta
sudo service tlp stop
sudo rm -r /tmp/.delllct
sudo service delllctservicecontent stop

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: i'm unable to install or remove any packages, it always tells me there are `unmet dependencies`

Comment: You can't remove packages? o_O

Comment: It tells me `The following packages have unmet dependencies` is there any way to ignore and bypass

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333438/can-i-have-ubuntu-forget-about-unmet-dependency-errors) they tell there is no way to make ubuntu forget unmet dependencies.

Comment: Try this `sudo dpkg -r --force-all mongodb-server`

Comment: Yes I did `sudo dpkg -r --force-all mongodb-org-server` , it said `dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:`, and i tried ` sudo apt-get -f install`,  it gives the same errors as before

Comment: Give me the output of `apt-cache policy mongodb-org-server`

Comment: its `mongodb-org-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     3.0.6 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29716/discussion-between-a-b-and-manoj-kumar).